# Custom youtube player in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use YouTube API for my app. I use `youtube_player_flutte`.Is there a way to customize a youtube player or maybe use another player + youtube API.
I am showing you what I don't like in youtube API.Is there a way to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you API for YouTube , I don't think that's possible .
So i recommend search again in pub.dev, if not you can choose another way to show the videos